Yii2 Bad Request (#400) posting a form in a Docker container
I have a docker container based on php:7.2.34-apache.
I have created a model and a CRUD via Gii.
The form for the update of the model doesn't work because when I POST the system thows "Bad Request (#400) Unable to verify your data submission." error.
If I set
'enableCsrfValidation' => false,
the pages reloads without saving.
The form is made with ActiveForm so in the page there is the hidden input with the csrf field valorized.
Any idea about the issue?
